# Wordpress The Next Posts

Tags: posts, previous, next

So for previous and next posts I used this from wordpress codex

```
<div class="navigation">
    <p>
        <?php posts_nav_link('&#8734;','Go Forward In Time','Go Back in Time'); ?>
    </p>
</div>
```

I want to change that.. in the wp-admin, I used on settings -> reading -> Blog pages show at most = 5 so I wanted to have a button to click on and load like 5 more posts, every time you click on the button and you are on the bottom of the page ... to give you an example cuz my english is not that good..

https://instagram.com/menwithclass

at first you see the some posts and if you scroll down, you click on a button and it loads more posts..

is that somehow possible to load the posts on the same page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a tutorial about infinite scroll - http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/wordpress-infinite-scroll/

Maybe it will help you too. you need JetPack as plugin to do it! :) Worked for me fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the wordpress plugin '[Ajax Load More](https://wordpress.org/plugins/ajax-load-more/)' which facilitates you with the features of loading more posts on the same page.

Comment: Sounds good.
But is there any way to achieve it without a plugin?